# Pointer to incomplete type is not allowed, defining global struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

well i'm having difficulties, i cant work with struct pointers in other .c files,
always when i'm passing pointers to structs to functions not in the same .c file as the struct it annoying me with such messages. and also when i can't access struct members of one struct from other .c file i'm g
what am i doing wrong? my includes? that's for example two of my structs .h files:

Server.h  :

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H
typedef struct Server_s* Server;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Company.h"
#include "Client.h"
#include "Order.h"
#include "SMSServer.h"
#include "MMSServer.h"

Server InstallServer(CompanyL pcompanyList , ClientL pclientList , OrderL porderList);
void RunServer(Server pmainServer);
void OrdersToDoPerTimestamp(FILE *result , Server pmainServer , int currentTimestamp);
#endif
```

Client.h   :

```
#ifndef _CLIENT_H
#define _CLIENT_H
typedef struct Client_s* Client;
typedef struct ClientNODE* ClientL;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Server.h"
ClientL InstallClients(CompanyL pcompanyList , char* pfileName);
void AppendClientNode(ClientL pclientList , CompanyL pcompanyList , char* ptelNumber , char* pclientType , char* pclientCredit);
Client FindClient(ClientL pclientList, char* pclientTelNumber);
double getCostAndChargeSMSMessage(Client sourceNumber , Company sourceNumberCompany);
#endif
```

i can create one struck type in other .c files, but later can't access their members?
please guide me a bit.

Comment: It would be very helpful to indicate what the actual error message is and what line(s) the compiler is complaining about. Also, do you actually have `struct` definitions for `Server`, `Client`, `Client_s`?

Comment: You don't appear to have actually defined the struct anywhere. Also, please format your code correctly.

Comment: Do you intend for `struct Server_s` and `struct Client_s` to be the same?

Comment: yes the names end with _s and i use pointers, that's the typedefs...

Comment: and yeah i was needed to make it generic with function pointers but it's too complicated for me to make the change now, so i'm having struct for each object in the program.  all i want is to access the whole structs members from multiple .c files.. how??

Comment: i get some "Specifies undefined struct/union '...' "   error when compling...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to give access struct members to other files, you have to put the full struct definition into the header file. E.g:

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H
struct Server_s {
    int id;
};
typedef struct Server_s* Server;
#endif
```

The definition-less idiom you are currently using is meant to hide the implementation details from outside users: others can pass and receive pointers to the structures, but only the defining file (Server.c) can use the struct members.

Comment: thank you! finally i can understand what i was doing wrong all those days. going to check...

Answer (score 1):

You can only access struct members if the definition is available, so you'd have to define it in a header if you want to access them from multiple c files.

Comment: ok and how i should define it and where? i think i already did, i define it in the struct.h file, and then i include it where ever i need it in other .h file which will be included from other .c file. is it not enough?

Comment: You haven't provided your struct.h file, how how will we know if it's correct.

Comment: Do you define the struct in the header file the same way you define it in a source file?